# Elegant BFS in ocaml

Tags: algorithm, ocaml, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I would like to repair my `bfs` function, its problem is that when it receives non-existant nodes it prints them as visited too.

And this function is already huge so adding a check like :

`if node not in graph then ...` would also bloat my function even more, which I would like to avoid because I want to see a shorter function which is "eye-debuggable".

Furthermore, I chose `Hashtable` because as opposed to the  `Set` :

1. It's mutable
2. It's an array but the `Set` is a balanced binary tree

(If your personal preference is to go with the `Set` please let me know why)

```
    type 'a graph = Gr of ('a * 'a list) list

    let get_neighbors node (Gr g) = 
        try List.assoc node g with Not_found -> []

    let bfs start g = 
        let v = Hashtbl.create 100 in (*ideally it should be the # of distinct nodes*)
        let q = Queue.create () in    (*v is for visited nodes*)

        let rec bfs' cur_n acc = 
                get_neighbors cur_n g |>
                List.iter
                (fun n -> 
                    try Hashtbl.find v n
                    with Not_found -> 
                        Hashtbl.add v n ();
                        Queue.push n q);
                Hashtbl.add v cur_n (); 
                try bfs' (Queue.pop q) (cur_n::acc)
                with Queue.Empty -> List.rev (cur_n::acc) in
                bfs' start []
```

Example :

```
    let g =  
        Gr [
             ('a', ['e'; 'b'; 'c']); 
             ('b', ['e'; 'd']); 
             ('e', ['d'; 'f']);
             ('g', ['t';'s'])
           ]

    # bfs 'a' g;;
    - : char list = ['a'; 'e'; 'b'; 'c'; 'd'; 'f']
    # bfs 'z' g;;
    - : char list = ['z'] (*doesn't make sense, g doesn't have 'z' node*)
```

Comment: To answer to your question about `Set` or `List`, if you need to find elements, `Set` is always better because the complexity of the search is `O(log(n))` whereas a `List` is `O(n)`.

Comment: @Lhooq you mean to use the `Set` to my graph data and not the `List`, right ?

Comment: 1) Hashtbl is the right thing to use here. 2) But Queue is maybe not. If the order of nodes visited does not matter a simple list will do. Just prepend the neighbours, don't append. 3) If a node ever points to itself you will enter an endless loop. Move the `Hashtbl.add v cur_n ();` to the start of the function. 4) You keep track of all visited nodes in `v` but also in `acc`. Then in the end you reverse `acc`. Again if the order does not matter why not create the result list from `v`? 5) If your graphs get bigger then list of lists is a really really slow choice.  Use set or hashtbl.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow thanks, I used acc so that I get the order in which the nodes were visited.

Comment: Goswin answered for me. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the `Not_found` exception in `get_neighbors` indicates a nonexistent node. But your code is treating this case is if it indicates a node with no successors.

If your graph is well structured, the neighbor lists shouldn't contain any nonexistent nodes. So the only place this node can come from is the initial call.

So I would move the handling of this Not_found exception out to the outermost level.

Comment: Do you mean, to handle the `Not_found` in the `bfs` function ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am proposing. (BTW you should unindent the last line of the code, it has a confusing indentation.)

Comment: Actually I would suggest not to handle Not_found in the `bfs` function. Don't handle it at all. If `bfs` is called with a nonexistent node then `get_neighbours` with raise Not_found and terminate the bfs.